# How to replace http for https before DOM Construct on load KMZ file with ArcGIS API JS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dojo, arcgis-js-api

I have an application and it is loaded with https, this application loads a map with a KMZ file, and the content of that file has external reference to a PNG image that is loaded with http. This causes the page's https to break.

Look at this example of how this is done.

```
var kmlUrl = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/geodera-bucket/filesds/5c2e82457cd9e62b0a453ce3-1578081436616-bushfireAlert.kmz";
var kml = new KMLLayer(kmlUrl);
map.addLayer(kml);
kml.on("load", function() {
  domStyle.set("loading", "display", "none");
});
```

https://codepen.io/krekto/pen/NWPYmRb

I want to replace these http references with https before loading external content.

My application uses AngularJS, JQuery and Dojo, the solution can be with any of these technologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(answered at duplicate question at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347046/how-to-replace-http-for-https-before-dom-construct-on-load-kmz-file-with-arcgis)

How about letting the browser do the work by adding this in the head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
      content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests